# Does my formula suggest the current definition of division by 0 is not correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I'm a junior in highschool and I came up with a formula to create repeating decimals. I've found a couple uses for it such as $O(log_{10}(n))$ "semi" compression algorithm using nothing but algebra (no string utilities besides string length). But it does create a problem with division by 0.

Here's a demo of the algorithm if you're interested (in python): https://repl.it/@Hexcede/Pure-Math-Compression-Py

My formula is as follows: $\frac{digits}{10^{digitLength} - 1}$
Digits are the "repeating" digits and digitLength is the number of digits.
Example: $\frac{123}{10^{3} - 1} = 0.\overline{123}$

I asked myself the question, what if you reduce digitLength? It turns out this basically "shifts" each repetition of the digits to the left/right and overlapping digits are summed.
$$\frac{123}{10^{2} - 1} = 0.\overline{124}$$
$$\frac{123}{10^{1} - 1} = 0.\overline{136}$$

And here's where my problem came in. What if digitLength is 0?
Shouldn't it overlap itself fully meaning it would be infinite following the infinite sum idea? And what if digits is 0 and digitLength is 0? If it's an infinite sum of 0 shouldn't it be 0?

And intuitively, shouldn't it make sense for $\frac n0$ to be infinity? To divide you're basically saying how many times you have to add the divisor to get $n$. $2 + 2 = 4$. $4/2 = 2$. But if the divisor is 0 you add 0 infinitely and never reach $n$. And where $n = 0$ you already start with 0 before you've added anything so 0/0 is 0.

So I tested out current contradictions for this version of division by 0.
$\frac{0 * 1}{0} = \frac{0 * 2}{0}$

Simplifying you get:
$$\frac{0}{0} * 1 = \frac{0}{0} * 2$$
$$0 * 1 = 0 * 2$$
$$0 = 0$$
This works correctly.

Additionally if you say $\frac00= 0$ you say $0 * 0 = 0$ which holds true.

And finally if you say that it is is undefined ($0.n + 0.n + 0.n...$ = $n/(10^0 - 1)$ are you saying these are no longer equivalent thus breaking the infinite sum property of repeating decimals shown above?

Comment: $123/(10^2-1)=1.242424...$ not $0.1242424...$, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Infinity is not a number, and there is no good way to create a new number for it.

If you try to use $\infty$ as a number that's the result of the computation $1/0$ you sacrifice some of the rules of arithmetic you really don't want to live without. In particular, the identity
$$
\frac{a}{b} \times b = a
$$
now fails when $b=0$.

This argument is independent of how you want to deal with a $0$ denominator in your algorithm. There you can either bail out with an error or error message, or make some choice that's consistent with the particular application.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are not correct.  I suspect you are using the overline in a nonstandard way, thinking about the exponent on the $10$ to tell you about the repeat.
$$\frac{123}{10^{2} - 1} = \frac {123}{99}=1+\frac {24}{99}=1.\overline{24}$$
You missed the left shift by one digit as well as the reduction in the repeat length.  Similarly
$$\frac{123}{10^{1} - 1}= \frac {123}9=13\frac 6{9}= 13.\overline{6}$$
Your argument about reducing the length to zero does not work.  By starting with an assumption and deriving a truth, you cannot derive the truth of the assumption because false$\implies$ true is true.  Following your argument I could claim 
$$1=2\\1\cdot 0=2 \cdot 0\\0=0$$ so we know $1=2$